# BibTex error when fields have {'s around them

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm gradually getting used to using BibTeX for citing references in my LaTeX documents, but I've run into a bit of a problem. I'm using natbib so that I get Harvard-style citations, but I get a warning saying that my references cannot be resolved when I try and cite a reference. I've done some investigation of this and found that when my references are in the form below:

```
@article{Wasson:1983,
    Annote = {10.1038/304337a0},
    Author = {Wasson, R. J. and Hyde, R.},
    Date = {1983/07/28/print},
    Date-Added = {2010-10-29 10:34:27 +0100},
    Date-Modified = {2010-10-29 10:36:13 +0100},
    Day = {28},
    Journal = {Nature},
    M3 = {10.1038/304337a0},
    Number = {5924},
    Pages = {337--339},
    Title = {Factors determining desert dune type},
    Ty = {JOUR},
    Url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/304337a0},
    Volume = {304},
    Year = {1983},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/304337a0}}
```

It gives an error, but when I change the contents to have quotes around them rather than curly braces it works fine. The problem is that most sources (for example Google Scholar, and all of the output from BibDesk) appear to use braces.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Is there a setting I can change somewhere to deal with this?

Comment: I removed the 'pdftex' and 'latex' tags

Comment: If the answer bellow doesn't solve your problem, consider posting an example of an entry that produces the error you describe.

Comment: @Juan - my question has an example in it already, which produces an error when I use it. Does anyone else get an error when using that bit of BibTex?

Comment: Nop. It compiles fine for me. I created a `.bib` file with your example as the single entry and then cited it from a minimal LaTeX document (using `natbib` as you said).

Comment: Same here, works fine.

Comment: What I'm confused by is the DOI appearing in _four_ different fields...

Comment: He probably copied the listing from BibDesk or something like that, which to cover all the bases tries to put the non-standard information in all non-standard fields it feels appropriate.

Comment: @robintw: The entry you posted is not the one that causes the problems, apparently. It must be another one of them. Read the output produced by bibtex. That should help you narrow it down. You should also tell us what the error is so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Sorry about this guys. I've just got back to this problem and found that if I reduce the bibtex file to just this entry it works fine. I've now built my BibTeX file up again, and it now works fine. I think it was the strange bits that BibDesk was putting at the end of my file to say what references where in what categories that was causing problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly normal for bibtex fields to be enclosed in braces, but it is possible that there is a stray { or } inside the field, and that is not allowed: the content should have balanced braces. I can't quite explain why it works if you use ", but in any case I suspect something is broken in the bib file.

See [this link](http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/xdkbibtex/bibtex_summary.html) for a good, readable description of what is and is not allowed in a bib file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide an example with a minimal tex file as well? This bit of BibTeX does not produce any errors for me, may be it is related to your LaTeX file and/or something peculiar with your natbib.